# Prevent Upload Until After Processing Has Finished (Function With Callback?)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an Upload Button in an app that uploads a deliveries object, but I don't know how to delay the Upload part of the routine kicking off until it has finished the processing part. I have currently used a sticky plaster of a timeout to hopefully allow for all processing to finish, but I think that I need to put another function with a callback in somewhere.

Full code is below, but it is this bit that needs to finish processing before it moves on to the part of the function that is inside the setTimeout.

```
var deliveries = Enumerable.From(results).Select(function (r) {
    r.transactionDate = r.transactionDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    return r;
}).ToArray();
```

Full code:

```
me.uploadClicked = function () {
   playClicked();
    coreViewModel.busyMessage("Processing delivery data...");

    deliveryRepository.GetTodaysDeliveries(function (results) {
        var deliveries = Enumerable.From(results).Select(function (r) {
            r.transactionDate = r.transactionDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            return r;
        }).ToArray();


        window.setTimeout(function () {
            coreViewModel.busyMessage("Uploading delivery data...");

            var objUploadDeliveries = Object.create({
                objStore: Object.create({
                    storeTypeID: coreViewModel.store.storeTypeID(),
                    storeID: coreViewModel.store.id()
                }),
                objDeliveries: deliveries
            });

            var comm = new URLHelper();
            var xhr = $.ajax({
                url: comm.hosturl() + "UploadDelivery",
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function(xh) { xh.setRequestHeader("token", coreViewModel.token); },
                data: objUploadDeliveries,
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (result) {
                    if (!result) {
                        playError();
                        return;
                    }
                    playUploadComplete();
                },
                error: function (x, e) {
                    playError();
                    errorHandler(x, e);
                    },
                timeout: 60000
            });
        }, 20000);
    });
}
```

The GetTodaysDeliveries function is as follows:

```
GetTodaysDeliveries: function (callback) {
    deliverysDatabase.GetDeliveries(function (results) {
        $.each(results, function (index, result) {
            result.transactionDate = moment(result.transactionDate).utc();
        });

        var todaysResults = Enumerable.From(results).Where(function (r) {
            return moment().isSame(r.transactionDate, 'day');
        }).ToArray();

        return callback(todaysResults);
    });
}
```

and the deliverydatabase.GetDeliveries function inside that is as follows:

```
GetDeliveries: function (callback) {
    var me = this;

    db.transaction(
        function (context) {
            context.executeSql("SELECT barcode, titleName, delivered, expected, isNews, supplier, supplierId, transactionDate FROM delivery ORDER BY titlename", [], function (context, result) {
                if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                    var results = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                        results.push(result.rows.item(i));
                    }

                    return callback(results);
                } else {
                    return callback([]);
                }
            }, me.ErrorHandler);
        }
        , me.ErrorHandler);
}
```

Comment: What are you seeing that makes you think processing isn't finishing before the upload?

Comment: Jason, the deliveries object sometimes is null when it is received by the web service, other times it is passed but the delivered property is a knockout function rather than the value of the function

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything asynchronous about the block in question so there's no reason for it to -not- finish before the upload. I don't see anything wrong with your callbacks. Can you provide a sample of the data returned? Are you able to reproduce the problem with a given data set or is it intermittent?

Comment: Hi Jason, I must be misunderstanding, as I thought the Ajax call to the server would take place as soon as it could. It is an intermittent issue, but I can reproduce it more often by lowering the timeout value, and increasing the amount of data needing to be processed into the deliveries object.

Most often I see it as 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' for the objUploadDeliveries object that contains objDeliveries.

Comment: Unless the code posted doesn't match your codebase the processing should finish first. The processing and upload are both inside the callback of GetTodaysDeliveries so neither can begin until the results are returned. Once inside the callback the processing executes first, and there's nothing async about the processing so it has to finish before execution even reaches the upload. The upload itself is ajax and will be asynchronous but that only means execution will continue to the next line -below- the upload before the upload finishes. It has no bearing on the processing bit above it.

Comment: Jason, that's grand, thank you, you've been a great help. I guess that I've been approaching the problem wrong and -assuming- it was executing the code at the same time when in reality it's probably somewhere earlier in the code that means my deliveries object is null before being baked into the objUploadDeliveries object. I will ask another SO question on the LINQ code as I don't understand enough about it to debug that.